Closed form for $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} k(-1)^k \sum_{i=k}^{2n-1} {2n \choose i+1} {i \choose n}$?
I've found this sum:
$$S(n) = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} k(-1)^k \sum_{i=k}^{2n-1} {2n \choose i+1} {i \choose n}$$
The inner sum is elliptical iirc, but perhaps the double sum has a nice expression. We can change the order of summation and the expression becomes a tiny bit better to manipulate, but I went straight to try some induction on it. So here is the sequence $S(n)$ as $n$ goes from $1$ to $10$:
$$-1,5,-61,614,-5762, 52093, -460099, 3999356,-34363396, 292676603,...$$
I tried some polynomial interpolations but they didn't stabilize on the values I tried (something like $n=6$). Then I did suppose $S(n) = (-1)^n a^n p(n)$ for $p(n)$ a polynomial and $a=2$ or $a=4$, it also didn't stabilize. I have good reasons to believe
$$S(n) = a \frac{(-1)^n}{n+d} { 4n+b \choose n+c}$$
for some constants $a,b,c$ and $d$ but I'm not sure how to find those constants. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?
EDIT: I made a Python program that verifies those constants and I got nothing for each on the interval $[0,19]$, perhaps $S(n) = \mathcal{o}((\frac{256}{27})^n\frac1{n \sqrt n})$, indeed $\frac1n{4n \choose n}$ begin dominating a bit after $n=40$
EDIT2: changing order of summation: $$n \le k \le i \le 2n-1 \implies S(n) = \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \sum_{k=n}^i {2n \choose i+1} {i \choose n}k(-1)^k = \\ = \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} {2n \choose i+1} {i \choose n} \sum_{k=n}^i (-1)^k k = \frac14 \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} {2n \choose i+1} {i \choose n}[(-1)^i(2i+1) + (-1)^n(2n-1)] $$
EDIT3: apparently we have an hypergeometric function:
$$_2F_1(1-n,n+1;n+2;-1) = - \frac{(n+1)!}{2(2n+1)!}f^{(n)}(0), f(z) = (1-z)^{-n}(1+z)^{2n+1}$$
EDIT4: By "closed form" I mean a finite expression of few terms which involves only adition, multiplication, potentiation, rational roots, factorials, combinations, floors functions of integers related to $n$. Not involving any explicit algorithm $\mathcal O(n)$ in the final result nor any function not expressed above.

For $n>1$ wolframAlpha proveds the closed form: $$\frac{(-1)^n}{4}\left(-1+{2n\choose n}\frac{n(2n-1)}{n+1} _2F_1(1-n,n+1;n+2;-1)\right)$$

@Zima thanks, so there is no closed form

Unless that hypergeometric function can be evaluated explicitly there isn't

Converting and using this formula shows $S(n)$ likely can be written in terms of the $n$th derivative of some $(1-z)^u (1+z)^v$ at $z=0$. Would this help?

@Tyma Gaidash we have a pochhammer symbol in the denominator of your first link, that doesn't help

@ТymaGaidash you're right, I'll edit the question and add my discover

I believe this double sum represents the coefficients of the polynomial $(x-1)(1+x^2+...+x^{2(m-1)})$ which looks more doable

@hellofriends I can't see how they are the coefficients. The coefficient of $x^2$ is $-1$, while $S(2)=5$, is there something I'm missing?

@Zima not all of them are $-1$, only the first $m$ in my formula, but $m$ really is $n$.

@Zima to be explicit, the first inner sum represents the coefficients of the polynomial $(x-1)(1+x^2+...+x^{2(n-1)})$ which are not $-1$ (from the $m$ th forward), not the double sum, my B

The notion of a "closed form" is not well-defined.  What do you mean by this?  Often, we mean "representable with some algebra of functions"---for example, we might say that a function can be represented by some closed form if it is in the algebra generated by addition, multiplication, and exponentiation (i.e. it can be written as some finite combination of sums/differences, products/quotients, and exponential expressions).  But this only one meaning of the phrase.  In order for your question to be answerable, you need to first pin down the meaning of "closed form".

@XanderHenderson It's pretty easy to understand what the OP is asking for, I don't see why the question was closed. He asked for a formula that doesn't include a sum with progressively more terms as $n$ gets large, I don't think it's unreasonable, there are plenty of similar questions on this site

@Zima I mean, they could have waited a bit more, but this sum likely doesn't have a closed form I'm afraid. I almost deleted it myself after you had shown me it was an hypergeometric series

@Zima You say that, but they rejected a solution in terms of a hypergeometric function. So I disagree that it is clear. "Closed form" is not well-defined.
